# Migration of SharePoint 2013 to SharePoint 2016

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, 2016, migration, content-database

After Mounting the database on SharePoint 2016, below is an error I'm getting:

> Could not load file or assembly 'VDR_Mail_Event_Solution, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8f7265d6d3991bc8' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1):

Did you have a custom solution/feature related to "VDR_Mail_Event_Solution" on you SharePoint 2013 farm?

If you have deployed custom solutions/features on your SharePoint 2013 farm, to make sure them work on your SharePoint 2016, you need to re-deploy them on your SharePoint 2016 before you mount database on SharePoint 2016 farm.

Or, if you don't continue using these solutions/features, you can remove them on your SharePoint 2013 firstly, then backup your database and mount it on your SharePoint 2016.